# Interface and its inheritances

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, interface

```
interface myI
{
    public function myF();
}

class myTest implements myI
{
    public function myF()
    {
        echo 'blah';
    }
}

class myTest2 extends myTest 
{

}
```

Above is a simple Interface requiring classes to implement the myF function. Now, if a class implements that interface, then all other inheritance of that class won't be require to implement it, right?

I tested:

```
 $lists = new myTest2();    
if($lists instanceof myI){
            echo 'yes' . "<br />";
    }
```

And it outputted yes.

Then I changed

Then I changed

```
   class myTest2 extends myTest
```

to

```
   class myTest2 extends myTest implements myI
```

and it still outputted 'yes', even though myTest2 did not implement the myF function.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It's extending the base class which already implements the interface and defines the method.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your parent class myTest covers implementation of interface. You can overwrite implementation in myTest2.

Answer (score 0):

Because `myTest2` inherits `myF` from `myTest`. Implementing the interface, `myTest2` already has the function inherited from `myTest`, so it is in check with the interface's requirements.